# How to use graph to show AzureAD user list?

Tags: azure, graph, active-directory

I've created an AzureAD called *Blopp* and now I wish to use the REST graph tool to list all of its users, as [Jimaco Brannian](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-graph-api-quickstart/) suggests.

The problem is that I only get an error, most likely due to security issues. So, my string in the URL needs additional parameters, I'd guess - the user name and password.

> https://graph.windows.net/Blopp.OnMicrosoft.com/users?api-version=1.5

```
<error>
  <code>Authentication_MissingOrMalformed</code>
  <message xml:lang="en">Access Token missing or malformed.</message>
</error>
```

How do I provide the credentials there?

Also, a follow-up question. How do I use the UI he describes? When I navigate to [that page](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net) and change the text from *https://graph.windows.net* to include my AzureAD as his pattern shows, it only jumps to the original text... A bit confusing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to Add an Application to AzureAD to Allow Read Access to the AzureAD

The below Article provides you with a Step by Step Guide on how to do it

http://justazure.com/azure-active-directory-part-5-graph-api/

Comment: Oh, so I need to create a whole application in order to talk to the graph of my account? That's a lot of work. I was expecting something quickish to obtain tokens that I specify myself (and simply type those in). It's not a professional solution, of course. I just wanted to play around with it for a while to get a touch of how it behaves.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to create a "whole application". The Azure AD "Web Application" that you need to add is more of a configuration construct that you create in the Azure management portal. It doesn't have to have an actual web application instance coded to work. Set it up in the portal, get its client id and key and use those in your throwaway code.